# Cannot set property XXX of undefined in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined

I want to initialize an interface in TypeScript.

```
export interface TestGroup {
  "id": number;
  "type": TestType;
  "interval"?: number;
}


import {TestGroup} from "../../gen/api";
public functionConfig: TestGroup;
.
.
.
this.functionConfig.id = testGroup.functionTestConfig;
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

Could you please help me?

Comment: you need to initialize functionConfig to some value, right now it is undefiend and you end up doing undefined.id which is not valid javascript.

Comment: What is `this`?  Where was `this.functionConfig` set?  Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Well you declare `functionConfig` but you don't assign it any value, therefore it is undefined. If you do something like `this.functionConfig = { test : "value" }` or even just `this.functionConfig = { }` it will be defined, so afterwards, you can do `this.functionConfig.id = "whatever"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `functionConfig` has a type but it is actually `undefined`. So you need to initialize it:

```
public functionConfig: TestGroup = {id: 0, type: 'YourTestTypeHere'};
```

or your default values for it

Comment

```
var activateOnWeekDay: Array<boolean> = [];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please tell me: How can I initialize Array<boolean> when I have a variable like "activateOnWeekDay": Array<boolean>;

Comment: See edited part. You just need to assign an empty array

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by initializing an empty `object` {}.

```
export interface TestGroup {
  id: number;
  type: TestType;
  interval?: number;
}


import {TestGroup} from "../../gen/api";
public functionConfig: TestGroup = {};        <=====Assign empty object
.
.
.
this.functionConfig.id = testGroup.functionTestConfig;
```